Using hugging_face load_dataset in VSCode
I am trying to load a training dataset in my VS Code notebook but keep getting an error. This happens exclusively in VS Code, since when I run the same notebook in Colab there is no problem in loading.
Here is the code snippet which returns the error
from datasets import load_dataset df = load_dataset("glue","mrpc")
And In VS Code,return this:
EmptyDatasetError: The dataset repository at 'nyu-mll/glue' doesn't contain any data files

You need to first Check Your Entire Library is Installed or Not.?
if library is install than execute your code in sequence.!

The libraries are install.
